Downloading an Excel file from an URL using Python
The URL for Excel file is this:
https://www.gso.gov.vn/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/IIP-ENG.xlsx
I have this code:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

url = 'https://www.gso.gov.vn/wp-content/uploads/' + datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(30), '%y') +'/' + datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(30), '%m') + '/IIP-ENG.xlsx'

import requests
resp = requests.get(url, verify=False)
output = open('IIP.xlsx', 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()

I can see a file being downloaded but I can't open it in Office Excel. The file is corrupted.
resp


<Response [404]>

I also cant open using this code:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(open('IIP.xlsx', 'rb'),sheet_name=0, engine='openpyxl')
print(df.head(5)) 


BadZipFile error. The file is not a Zip file.

How to fix this ?

Why is your url dynamically constructed?

It changes every month. Based on the current month and year.

The issue is with the year format, '%y' will give 24, you need '%Y' for 2024
datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(30), '%Y')


Fixed:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

url = 'https://www.gso.gov.vn/wp-content/uploads/' + datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(30), '%Y/%m') + '/IIP-ENG.xlsx'

import requests
resp = requests.get(url, verify=False)
if resp.status_code == 200:
    output = open('IIP.xlsx', 'wb')
    output.write(resp.content)
    output.close()
else:
    print("File cannot be downloaded.")

The year and month part should be in "YYYY/mm" format and the pattern is "%Y/%m" (and no need to format twice).
Also, remember to verify the status code before you go on with the response content.

What you have given is itself a downlaodable link. Just go the browser > Settings > download and select the place you want to dowload. Now just run the script from the terminal's/command prompr's python interpreter.
from selenium import webdriver as dr
url= "https://www.gso.gov.vn/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/IIP-ENG.xlsx"
dr = dr.Chrome()
dr.get(url)

You'll see that  the file getting dowloaded in your required destination.

This code snippet is part of a large project. This particular URL will become outdated by the time project is completed. The code should work for all future URLs to come.

Would be the html structure remain same ever? For instance same class/ Id for thge new file also?

I don't know about html structure. I think it can change. But last month URL was:
https://www.gso.gov.vn/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/IIP-ENG.xlsx" .
The month before that it was : 2024/01 etc...

Dont worry abt the url. Just find out if class_name or id of the a tag remains the same. To do that open the page in browser, right click ans select inspect. As you can move the mouse in thr console, yoy'll find the main html apage element also selected. So select the respective link, right click and selecct and then copy selector, Paste into a text editor. If the selector remains same in the last month  and this month also, then  you can easily downlod.

The webpage URL also changes every month. https://www.gso.gov.vn/en/data-and-statistics/2024/03/index-of-industrial-production-in-march-of-2024/

@prashanthmanohar, It looks like the main domain is same. So we can find out some logics to download
